# Can NodeJS MySQL Database be accessed by other computer programs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, npm

I need to setup mysql database. So, that NodeJS server and external program can access the same mysql database. So, I installed mysql with `npm install mysql` on the terminal. I test ran nodejs mysql sample code. It works; created database and table. But now, I want this other program to get access to this mysql database. Can this be done? or Do I have to actually install MySQL driver for my system?

Comment: other nodejs Programms c++ vb net?

Comment: yes... like programs written other languages pascal, C++ VB, etc...

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql` package is just a way for Node.js to access a MySQL database. Other programs will also be able to access the same database if you install the appropriate drivers/libraries for them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the drivers here called connctors  for all languages that are used and don't have them integrated.

[image: see installer]